# Creating the xml format to pass to zeep

Tags: python, xml, zeep

I'm new to zeep. 
I have the following that works very well:

```
import zeep

from zeep.cache import SqliteCache

from zeep.transports import Transport
wsdl = 'https://emaapitest.eset.com/Services/v2015_1/MSPService.svc?singleWsdl'
transport = Transport(cache=SqliteCache())
client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl, transport=transport )
```

With the above I can use the defined API for most calls.
For example:

```
data = {'Username': 'xxxx123',  'Password': 'Secretpassword'}
loginreq = client.service.Login(data)

data = {'LoginID': 'xxxyyy', 'Token': 'gregrwevds543',  'CompanyID': 123}
company_details = client.service.GetCompanyDetails(data)
```

That all works well.
However the API call to UpdateSite needs a different format as below:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msp="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Requests">
       <soapenv:Header/>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <tem:UpdateSite>
         <tem:request>
            <msp:LoginID>123abc</msp:LoginID>
            <msp:Token>hpjzncpduqyfreyakcsdilqv</msp:Token>
                  <msp:LicenseRequests>
                       <LicenseRequest xmlns:d7="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Requests"
                    i:type="d7:LicenseCreateRequest" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.ViewModels">
                           <d7:ProductCode>112</d7:ProductCode>
                           <d7:Quantity>3</d7:Quantity>
                           <d7:Trial>false</d7:Trial>
                       </LicenseRequest>
                 </msp:LicenseRequests>
            <msp:SiteID>123456</msp:SiteID>
         </tem:request>
          </tem:UpdateSite>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

That is I need to change the namespace on the LicenseRequest.
Is there any way I can generate this xml (say using etree maybe) and then pass this into zeep?
Exact syntax would be a great help.
Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: By the way I am using zeep==2.4.0

Comment: To debug you can get the request xml which is generated by zepp http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/transport.html#debugging

Comment: Check this variant with plugin https://stackoverflow.com/a/49310002/5274713 it could help in some cases.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example to format the SOAP Web Services XML message per the WSDL:

In this example, I found the namespace prefixes assigned by Zeep in `client.wsdl.dump()`; see example of this near the bottom of the answer.

```
>>> import zeep
>>> client = zeep.Client('https://emaapitest.eset.com/Services/v2015_1/MSPService.svc?singleWsdl')
>>> # note - the namespace ns2 was assigned by zeep - see client.wsdl.dump() tip later in this answer
>>> license_create_type = client.get_type('ns2:LicenseCreateRequest')
>>> # Creating an empty object reminds me of the property names, so I don't have to guess
>>> license_create_type()
{
    'Note': None,
    'ProductCode': None,
    'Quantity': None,
    'ServerName': None,
    'Trial': None
}
>>> my_create = license_create_type(ProductCode=112,Quantity=3,Trial=False)
>>> my_create
{
    'Note': None,
    'ProductCode': 112,
    'Quantity': 3,
    'ServerName': None,
    'Trial': False
}
>>> my_type = client.get_type('ns2:SiteUpdateRequest')
>>> # Reference for specifying arrays in Zeep: https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/145#issuecomment-321614947
>>> req = my_type(LoginID="123",Token="mytoken",LicenseRequests={'LicenseRequest':[my_create]})
>>> # To call the service:   (assuming valid credentials?)
>>> # client.service.UpdateSite(req)
```

Here's the Python view of the web service request:

```
>>> req
{
    'LoginID': '123',
    'Token': 'mytoken',
    'Active': None,
    'LicenseRequests': {
        'LicenseRequest': [
            {
                'Note': None,
                'ProductCode': 112,
                'Quantity': 3,
                'ServerName': None,
                'Trial': False
            }
        ]
    },
    'Name': None,
    'SecurityAdminRequests': None,
    'SiteID': None,
    'SupportLegacyKey': None
}
```

Here's the XML view of the web service request:

```
>>> # Debugging output to see raw XML...
>>> node = client.create_message(client.service, 'UpdateSite', req)
>>> from lxml import etree
>>> xml_str = etree.tostring(node, pretty_print=True).decode()
>>> print(xml_str)
```

```xml
<soap-env:Envelope xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap-env:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <wsa:Action>http://tempuri.org/IMSPService/UpdateSite</wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:c3d7d838-6ce8-477b-ad7d-23e99e800a80</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:To>https://emaapitest.eset.com/Services/v2015_1/MSPService.svc</wsa:To>
  </soap-env:Header>
  <soap-env:Body>
    <ns0:UpdateSite xmlns:ns0="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ns0:request>
        <ns1:LoginID xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Requests">123</ns1:LoginID>
        <ns2:Token xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Requests">mytoken</ns2:Token>
        <ns3:LicenseRequests xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Requests">
          <ns4:LicenseRequest xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.ViewModels" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="ns3:LicenseCreateRequest">
            <ns3:ProductCode>112</ns3:ProductCode>
            <ns3:Quantity>3</ns3:Quantity>
            <ns3:Trial>false</ns3:Trial>
          </ns4:LicenseRequest>
        </ns3:LicenseRequests>
      </ns0:request>
    </ns0:UpdateSite>
  </soap-env:Body>
</soap-env:Envelope>
```

Tip:  use `client.wsdl.dump()`

I usually start a project by reading `client.wsdl.dump()` to see the mappings generated by Zeep, starting from the "Bindings" and "Operations" at the bottom, then working backwards through the types.  This is usually all you need to get started.

```
>>> import zeep
>>> client = zeep.Client('https://emaapitest.eset.com/Services/v2015_1/MSPService.svc?singleWsdl')
>>> client.wsdl.dump()

Prefixes:
     myprefix: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Requests
     xsd: http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema
     ns0: http://tempuri.org/
     ns1: http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/
     ns3: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.Responses
     ns4: http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays
     ns5: http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MSPApi.Services.v2015_1.ViewModels

Global elements:
<SNIP - VERY LONG OUTPUT>

Global types:
<SNIP - VERY LONG OUTPUT>
     ns2:SiteUpdateRequest(LoginID: xsd:string, Token: xsd:string, Active: xsd:boolean, LicenseRequests: ns5:ArrayOfLicenseRequest, Name: xsd:string, SecurityAdminRequests: ns2:ArrayOfSecurityAdminRequest, SiteID: xsd:long, SupportLegacyKey: xsd:boolean)

<SNIP - VERY LONG OUTPUT>
Service: MSPService
     Port: BasicHttpBinding_IMSPService (Soap11Binding: {http://tempuri.org/}BasicHttpBinding_IMSPService)
         Operations:
<SNIP - VERY LONG OUTPUT>
            UpdateSite(request: ns2:SiteUpdateRequest) -> UpdateSiteResult: ns3:SiteDetailsResponse
<SNIP - VERY LONG OUTPUT>
>>>
```