# python zeep: send un-escaped xml as content

Tags: python, soap, soap-client, zeep

I think what I am trying to do is pretty much like [github issue in zeep repo](https://github.com/mvantellingen/python-zeep/issues/412) --- but sadly there is no response to this issue yet. I researched suds and installed and tried -- did not even get sending parameter to work and thought zeep seems better maintained?

Edit 1:
For sure I am not talking about [this](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/latest/client.html#creating-the-raw-xml-documents)

Comment: Any luck with this @Junchao Gu? I'm facing the same problem and I could use some help

Comment: @davidivad I gave up... I used zeep to generate sample message and then edited the sample message and send using curl.....

Comment: I found a solution, it may help you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a Plugin for editing the xml as a plain string. I used this plugin for keeping the characters '<' and '>' in a CDATA element.

```
from xml import etree
from zeep import Plugin

class my_plugin(Plugin):

    def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
        xml_string = etree.ElementTree.tostring(envelope)
        xml_string = xml_string.replace("&lt;", "<")
        xml_string = xml_string.replace("&gt;", ">")
        parser = etree.ElementTree.XMLParser(strip_cdata=False)
        new_envelope = etree.ElementTree.XML(xml_string, parser=parser)
        return new_envelope, http_headers
```

Then just import the plugin on the client:

```
client = Client(wsdl='url', transport=transport, plugins=[my_plugin()])
```

Take a look at the docs: http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Though I think it should be a feature to send raw message or send xml data.

Comment: This works on Python 3 by using `xmlString = etree.tostring(envelope, encoding='unicode')`. Additionally, you might also need to `xmlString = xmlString.replace("&amp;", "&")` if you have any ampersands.

Comment: py3: etree.tostring, etree.XMLParser, etree.XML

Answer (score 2):

On Python 3.9, @David Ortiz answer didn't work for me, maybe something has changed. The `etree_to_string` was failing to convert the XML to string.

What worked for me, instead of a plugin, I created a custom transport, that replaced the stripped tags with the correct characters, just like David's code, before the post was sent.

```
import zeep
from zeep.transports import Transport
from xml.etree import ElementTree

class CustomTransport(Transport):  
    def post_xml(self, address, envelope, headers):  
        message = ElementTree.tostring(envelope, encoding="unicode")  
        message = message.replace("&lt;", "<")  
        message = message.replace("&gt;", ">")  
        return self.post(address, message, headers)  


client = zeep.Client('wsdl_url', transport=CustomTransport())
```