# Overriding type from WSDL file with Zeep

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

The WSDL file for a ServiceNow SOAP API has the request_payload defined as a string when it's actually a dictionary. As a result any time I query the service, I get error:

`"ValueError: The String type doesn't accept collections as value".`

Section of WSDL file:

```
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://www.service-now.com/ChangeOperation" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.service-now.com/ChangeOperation" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <wsdl:types>
      <xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.service-now.com/ChangeOperation">
         <xsd:element name="changeOperationRequest">
            <xsd:complexType>
               <xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="source_system" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="source_uid" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="request_type" type="xsd:string"/>
                  <xsd:element maxOccurs="1" minOccurs="0" name="request_payload" type="xsd:string"/>
               </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
```

A successful SOAP request using SOAPUI:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns0="http://www.service-now.com/ChangeOperation">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns0:changeOperationRequest>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns0:source_system>Script</ns0:source_system>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns0:source_uid>131318</ns0:source_uid>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns0:request_type>getChangeRequests</ns0:request_type>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <ns0:request_payload>
            <start_date>2020-01-08T00:00:00</start_date>
            <status_list>Proposed</status_list>
            <owning_stream>IB IT</owning_stream>
            <full_details>no</full_details>
            <result_limit>100</result_limit>
         </ns0:request_payload>

      </ns0:changeOperationRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Is it possible to override the data type read in from the WSDL file, or alternatively is there any other way to force Zeep to send the field as a string?

I've tried unpacking the dictionary:

```
xml = client.service.changeOperationRequest(**request_dict)
```

and setting keyword arguments and only request_payload as a dictionary, but it results in the same error:

```
xml = client.create_message(client.service, 'changeOperationRequest', source_system='Script',source_uid='131318',request_type='getChangeRequests',request_payload=dictionary)
```

Even simply setting request_payload to the resulting xml doesn't work as the xml tags get expanded. Although I would rather not have to go down the route of manually creating the xml, that seems to somewhat defeat the point of using Zeep.

```
xml = client.create_message(client.service, 'changeOperationRequest', source_system='EQ CAB Report Script',source_uid='131318',request_type='getChangeRequests',request_payload='<start_date>2020-01-07T00:00:00</start_date><status_list>Proposed</status_list><owning_stream>IB IT</owning_stream><full_details>no</full_details><result_limit>100</result_limit>')
```

XML output:

```
<sn0:request_payload>&lt;start_date&gt;2020-01-07T00:00:00&lt;/start_date&gt;&lt;status_list&gt;Proposed&lt;/status_list&gt;&lt;owning_stream&gt;IB IT&lt;/owning_stream&gt;&lt;full_details&gt;no&lt;/full_details&gt;&lt;result_limit&gt;100&lt;/result_limit&gt;</ubs:request_payload>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have gone down the route of sending the dictionary as a string type instead. In order to not expand the escape the xml tags, I used the Zeep plugin helper.

Taken from: [python zeep: send un-escaped xml as content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655638/python-zeep-send-un-escaped-xml-as-content])

```
from zeep import Client, xsd, Plugin

class my_plugin(Plugin):

    def egress(self, envelope, http_headers, operation, binding_options):
        xmlString = ET.tostring(envelope, encoding='unicode')
        xmlString = xmlString.replace("&lt;", "<")
        xmlString = xmlString.replace("&gt;", ">")
        newenvelope = ET.XML(xmlString)
        return newenvelope, http_headers

# create the client:
client = Client(wsdl_url, transport=transport, plugins=[my_plugin()])

# call service as you would normally
client.service.changeOperationRequest()
```